# Comma separated values of multiple columns in single column in sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have a table with three column Id, Errorcode, ErrorDescription in which errorcode and errordescription columns have comma separated value in it

Here i need to concatenate the value of column 2 and 3, such as first value of column 2 - first value of column 3 and so on with comma(,) seprated

Example: Actual Table

| Id | Errorcode | ErrorDescription |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 204,201,33 | Invalid Object,Out Of Range,Invalid Format |
| 2 | 21,44 | FileInvalid,Invalid date |
| 3 | 20 | Invalid parse |

Required Output:

| Id | Error |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 204-Invalid Object, 201-Out Of Range, 33-Invalid Format |
| 2 | 21-FileInvalid, 44-Invalid date |
| 3 | 20-Invalid parse |

Comment: I **strongly** recommend you fix your design. *That* is the real solution here.

Comment: Agree with the above comment.  Get each CSV data point onto a separate record, and make your life easier.  Even if someone gives you an actual query here, it will likely have terrible performance and will be difficult to maintain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

..from sqlserver 2017 ..[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=0db7608939d0ad7e891aadab0a7f223c)

```
select *
from
(
values
(1, '204,201,33', 'Invalid Object,Out Of Range,Invalid Format'),
(2, '21,44', 'FileInvalid,Invalid date'),
(3, '20', 'Invalid parse')
) as t(Id, Errorcode, ErrorDescription)
cross apply
(
select string_agg(c.value+'-'+e.value, ', ') within group (order by cast(c.[key] as int)) as error
from openjson('["'+replace(string_escape(t.Errorcode, 'json'), ',', '","')+'"]') as c
join openjson('["'+replace(string_escape(t.ErrorDescription, 'json'), ',', '","')+'"]') as e on c.[key] = e.[key]
) as e;
```

..sqlserver 2016..[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=fc5de30576b7930b136065e600743e6b)

```
select *
from
(
values
(1, '204,201,33', 'Invalid Object,Out Of Range,Invalid Format'),
(2, '21,44', 'FileInvalid,Invalid date'),
(3, '20', 'Invalid parse')
) as t(Id, Errorcode, ErrorDescription)
cross apply
(
select stuff ((
   select ', '+c.value+'-'+e.value
   from openjson('["'+replace(string_escape(t.Errorcode, 'json'), ',', '","')+'"]') as c
   join openjson('["'+replace(string_escape(t.ErrorDescription, 'json'), ',', '","')+'"]') as e on c.[key] = e.[key]
   order by cast(c.[key] as int)
   for xml path(''), type).value('text()[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 2, '') as error
) as e;
```

Comment: I like this JSON-based approach (+1 from my side) . Two notes: 1) This answer really needs some explanations and 2) `STRING_AGG()` needs its `WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY CONVERT(int, c.[key]))` clause to get ordered results.

Comment: STRING_AGG() does not support in Sql Server 2016, substitute for STRING_AGG in SQL 2016

Comment: @ImranKadri … for sqlserver 2016 you could use for xml instead of string_agg()